Understanding section 8.16 of Calculus Vol. II by Apostol
I'm reviewing section 8.16 of Calculus Vol.II, regarding Level sets and tangent plane.
Let us consider a scalar field $f:S\subset\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$, the level set is defined as all those points in $x\in S$ such that $f(x)$ has a constant value. In short, $$L(c)=\{x:x\in S, f(x)=c\}.$$

Now, let's consider concretely an open set $S\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ and a scalar field $f:S\to\mathbb{R}$. We want to analyze one of the level sets (level surface in this case) of $f$, say $L(c)$. Consider a point $a\in S$ in this surface $L(c)$ and consider a curve $C$, which is in the surface and passes through $a$. The goal is to show that $\nabla f(a)$ is normal to the curve in $a$.
Assume $C$ is parametrized by a differentiable vector function $r$ which is defined in an open interval $I\subset\mathbb{R}.$
Since $C$ is in the level set(surface) $L(c)$, it holds that $$(f\circ r)(t)=f(r(t))=c$$ for all $t\in I$.
If $g(t)=(f\circ r)(t)$ for $t\in I$, then we can use the chain rule to claim $$g'(t)=\langle \nabla (f\circ r)(t), r'(t)\rangle.$$
But clearly $g(t)=c $ for all $t\in I$, which implies that $g'(t)=0$  for all $t\in I.$
Now, here comes the confusing part, in which Apostol claims the following:
"In particular, choosing $t_1$ in such a way that $g(t_1)=a$, we find that $$\langle \nabla f(a),r'(t_1)\rangle =0."$$
But how can $g(t_1)=a$? Shouldn't it be $r(t_1)=a$? I mean, $g=f\circ r$, where $r:I\to S$ and $f:S\to \mathbb{R}$. So, $g:I\to \mathbb{R}.$
How can an image of $g$ be an element of $\mathbb{R}^3$?  Is this an error/typo in the book?

Yes, you are of course correct. Even the best books do — sadly — have errors.

Ok, thanks. I spent a lot of time re-reading this section all over again since I thought I was misunderstanding something
